# Manipulate a new column after 'df.size()' function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

After I have executed a `df.size()` function as seen below (`df = Dataframe`) in the pandas module, I've obtained a new column beside the one labeled `No.`. However, I'm not sure how to manipulate this new column. This is because I don't know the label/key for this column.

For example, I want to express the values generated (in the new column) as a fraction of the sum of all these values in a new column. How can I do so?

```py
JuncNo = pd.read_csv(filename)
JuncNo_group = JuncNo.groupby('No.')
JuncSize = JuncNo_group.size()
JuncSize.head(n=6)
```

```
No.
1   122
2  2136 
3   561
4    91
5    10
6     3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: you can try  `JuncSize.name='Size'` and then reset index

Comment: what do u mean by reset index??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set name of new Series and reset index:

```
JuncSize = JuncSize.groupby('No').size()
JuncSize.name = 'size'
JuncSize = JuncSize.reset_index()
print JuncSize
```

But if you need add new column with same no of rows as original dataframe, you can use:

```
JuncSize['size'] = JuncSize.groupby('No').transform(np.size)
```

Example:

```
print JuncSize
  No Code
0  D   B2
1  B   B2
2  B   B3
3  B   B3
4  G   B3
5  B   B3

JuncSize['size'] = JuncSize.groupby('No').transform(np.size)
print JuncSize
  No Code size
0  D   B2    1
1  B   B2    4
2  B   B3    4
3  B   B3    4
4  G   B3    1
5  B   B3    4
```

```
JuncSize = JuncSize.groupby('No').size()
print JuncSize
No
B    4
D    1
G    1
JuncSize.name = 'size'
print JuncSize
No
B    4
D    1
G    1
Name: size, dtype: int64

JuncSize = JuncSize.reset_index()
print JuncSize
  No  size
0  B     4
1  D     1
2  G     1
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! But could u explain the function of JuncSize.name = 'size'??? What does the .name do?

Comment: Somehow the second code generated an error: pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3824)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3704)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12280)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12231)()

Comment: Should it be: JuncSize['size'] = JuncNo.groupby('No').transform(np.size) instead ?? And I typed the above, but there's an error (see above comment)...

Comment: Oh I understood... Thanks! :D

Comment: Hm, can I ask one more question? How can I then plot a Histogram of No. against Size?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know, because I never do it. But you can try [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/visualization.html#histograms)